# For a Flask app, is there a way to solve this error, "at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"..."?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Flask application that scrapes some websites for news and and have followed this tutorial with my own files: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_EO4RwABbA.

When I deploy the application to Heroku, the web app does not open as it should and I get something like the following errors:
`at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"`

My folder structure for my app looks like this:

```
- static
 - app.css
- templates
 - index.html
 - index2.html
 - index3.html
- app.py
- scrape1.py
- scrape2.py
- rateLimiter.py
- Procfile
- requirements.txt
- .gitignore
- venv
```

And my Procfile looks like this:
`web: gunicorn app:app`

Is there a known way of resolving this error?

I have tried changing the Procfile to `web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app`, checked the requirements.txt, and redeployed several times. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am happy to provide additional info.